# Writing SQL in Coderpad

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc, database-connection

I have an interview coming up in which I will write code in Coderpad.  What is the syntax to write SQL in Coderpad? (note Coderpad with an "r", not Codepad).

First, you select a language for Coderpad.  I am selecting Scala.

Here is a database they provide:

```
+--------------------+-----------+---------------+
| Table Name         | Row Count | Table Size KB |
+--------------------+-----------+---------------+
| departments        |         5 |       16.0000 |
| employees          |         6 |       32.0000 |
| employees_projects |         5 |       48.0000 |
| projects           |         3 |       16.0000 |
+--------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Here is Scala code that does work:

```
object Solution extends App {
  for (i <- 0 until 5) println("Hello, World!")
}
```

I want to run a simple SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM employees;
```

Note: I can write complex SQL in Spark with Scala.  I have written hundreds of Databricks Scala notebooks.  So, I do not need a primer on Scala or SQL.

I simply need the correct **SYNTAX** to write **any** simple SQL query in CoderPad just to get me started.  Thank you.

In other words, how do I insert a SQL statement into a Scala Object?

I tried:

```
object Solution extends App {
  //for (i <- 0 until 5) println("Hello, World!")
  val myTest = SQL("select * from employees").as(mapping *)
  myTest.take(1)


}
```

But get this error:

```
Solution.scala:6: error: not found: value SQL
  val myTest = SQL("select * from employees").as(mapping *)
               ^
Solution.scala:6: error: not found: value mapping
  val myTest = SQL("select * from employees").as(mapping *)
```

Comment: I had never heard of CoderPad until I read this question, so I looked it up.  I suggest you do the same.

Comment: I am logged in and using Coderpad.  I have spent 3 hours looking at dozens of searches and find almost nothing.

Comment: My question is generic:  how does one insert a SQL statement into Scala?

Comment: If that's your real question, you should rewrite the posted question.

Comment: There is not one single DB lib in Scala (as in other lang). Indicate which lib you are using if you want to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to connecto to your database just as you would do that in `Java`

They should provide you the database information to connect, so you need to do the following steps (writing from memory, sorry is something is missing)

import the required classes:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.Connection
```

Then define the properties to connect:

```
val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
val url = "jdbc:mysql://whateverServer/whateverDatabase"
val username = "user"
val password = "password"
```

Create the driver and then create the connection:

```
Class.forName(driver)
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
```

Then the statement and then run the query itself:

```
val statement = connection.createStatement()
val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from employees")
```

Comment: Thank you.  For other Coderpad users, please see my reply to Vincent Woo above.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the guy that makes CoderPad. Currently, you can't connect to MySQL databases in other language environments. That's something we want to do eventually, though.